# Match letters in a word

Tags: php, string, match

I have a link stored in a variable called `$word` like this:

```
$word = www.stack.com/angraze_mjhay_batao/help.php
```

I want to put a condition that if `stack` is found somewhere in the variable `$word` to do certain things.
I have done searching but everywhere there are functions to match words in the string. I cannot find any `PHP function` that does this job.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/check-if-string-contains-specific-words

Comment: peoples are not interested in telling problem solved or not and marking answer for others help. Wastage of effort and time. deleting my answer.

Answer (score 5):

[`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) should do the trick:

```
if (strpos($word, 'stack') !== false) {
    // do things...
}
```

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte indeed, how embarrassing. Fixed. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: He likes posting things :P

Comment: Please avoid changing code in edits (Other than whitespace/fixing formatting), especially if it changes the functionality. I know strings are normally surrounded by quotes, or single quotes, but this may be another issue the OP is having, and by editing it, you're assuming the author quoted it properly, and things may still not work right for him.

Comment: @FrankerZ fair enough. Carelessly just fixed it, but you are correct, that was a bad edit. Reverted the relevant parts (manually).

Comment: @Mureinik thanks for the help.btw how did you do that. i mean i tried posting it without that ignore line :P but they were not letting me post it. how they let you post it